# WHOIS fields translated to semantic

Tags: semantic-web, whois

There are a lot of "good" WHOIS interpreters, like [python-whois](https://github.com/joepie91/python-whois) or [phpWhois](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois), but each has its own interpretation of the fields and use different JSON fields and JSON structures...

I am looking for a ["Rosetta Stone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) semantic tool... It exists? Any sematic jargon as [SchemaOrg](https://schema.org/) or free RDF/JSON-LD/etc. interpretion, mapping fields of the raw whois file into its semantic.

---

Exemples of  **most frequent semantic usage**, and its fieldName-to-Semantic mapping:

- WHOIS field `domain` is [wikidata/Q32635](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q32635) or [uri4uri/Domain](http://uri4uri.net/vocab.html/#Domain).
- WHOIS field `owner` is  [schemaOrg/Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)'s [name](https://schema.org/name).
- WHOIS field `ownerid` is is  [schemaOrg/Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)'s  [vatID](https://schema.org/vatID).
- WHOIS field `country` is  [schemaOrg/Country](https://schema.org/Country)'s [addressCountry](https://schema.org/addressCountry).
- ... The question is: **where the another mappings?** where I find (or how to use) all the WHOIS fields?

---

PS: some of the "most frequent usage" semantic like WHOIS field `owner`, `registrar`  and `domain` are [*de facto* standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard), others no... The specific standards exists (!) in the context of the *registrar*, so, the cited tools (eg. [phpWhois's `whois.*.php`](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois/tree/master/src)) do the final interpretation, and this is the "Roseta's" *locus* of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Rosetta stone". The WHOIS protocol specification traditionally never provided any recommendation or guideline about what data should be disclosed, or which format should be used.

Therefore, any registry can virtually return a different response format and representation.

Comment: Hum... Sorry, I edited with better explanation, can you check?   Now the concept of "most frequent semantic usage" is in bold, and the PS explains that specific "*registrar* Roseta" of each country is in fact the source of the mapping, that each tool do (each tool in a better or worse way).

Answer (score 0):

Homework report.

### There are no "*standard* Rosetta stone"

No standard, of course: the current [RFC 3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912) WHOIS protocol specification say nothing...

It is, since 2004, a classic and well-documented problem of Internet. See this [SAC-051 ICANN 2011 report](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/sac-051-en.pdf), or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS#History), or [this 2012 blog](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/03/whois-protocol/).

### The new standard that replaced WHOIS!

What??!?

> *RDAP is a successor protocol to the very old WHOIS protocol.*
>  [RFC 7480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7480)

... But, as asked here, [How to successfully use RDAP protocol instead of whois](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37101250/287948)
, **there are no "working RDAP"**. So, meanwhile: we need WHOIS and a Rossetta for it!

### There are some "try to Rosetta"

As I cited, some APIs ([python-whois](https://github.com/joepie91/python-whois), [phpWhois](https://github.com/phpWhois/phpWhois), and others), do good job,  they translated all TXT *key-value* pairs of all [Internet top-level domain authorities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)... Need only a next step translation, that is a semantic indicator for each *key*.

When these API projects was developed, anyone heard of RDAP... But now, 2016, RDAP can be used as a reference to fix a standard JSON for WHOIS APIs.

Comment: As of 2019-08-26 RDAP is mandatory, by ICANN, for all gTLD registries and registrars.