# How to successfully use RDAP protocol instead of whois

Tags: linux, client, standards, whois, rdap

I'm a little confused about the new RDAP protocol and whenever it makes sense to pursue it any further. It looks to me like everyone agreed on it to be the successor of whois, but their databases seem empty. On ubuntu I tried rdapper, nicinfo and even their RESTful API:

http://rdap.org/domain/google.com
(this results in a "File not Found", but is correct according to [here](https://about.rdap.org/))

Am I misunderstanding something? Is RDAP dead, did the service not start yet or am I doing something wrong? Nicinfo returns this:

```
nicinfo -t domain google.com
# NicInfo v.1.1.0-alpha
# Query yielded no results.

[ NOTICE ] Terms of Service
         1 By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois
           Terms of Use
     About https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html

 [ ERROR ] DOMAIN NOT FOUND
      Code 404
         1 The domain you are seeking as 'google.com.' is/are not here.
```

rdapper returns this:

```
rdapper --TYPE domain google.com
Error: 404 No RDAP service for domains like 'google.com' is registered at rdap.org
```

If RDAP is supposed to be working, can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Meanwhile... We need to "mapping WHOIS to semantic", as trying here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/37455007/287948

Comment: Ops, `RDAP.ORG` is not an "offcial authority", its  WHOIS say that is  at Nassau, a *tax haven*... "Internet Domain Service BS Corp" is a commercial organization, so it is a false ".ORG".  There are a footer at `rdap.org` pages acknowledging that is no offcial service, is a `tau.uk.com` playground.  Try a [*RDAP client*](https://github.com/DNSBelgium/rdap).

Comment: Seems to me then like it's a dead wanabe standard then. Unless IANA decides to enforce RDAP on all registrars, I will not consider it any further... Tax heaven sounds about right. A non profit activity that seems to lead to nowhere, but people get paid for it.

Comment: Hi, perhaps there are a hope... See [this ICANN](https://www.icann.org/public-comments/rdap-profile-2015-12-03-en) complex report with no objective answer to the question or an objective "roadmap to RDAP implantation"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Direct short answer

The answer to "How to successfully use RDAP protocol instead of WHOIS?" is: **there are no way to successfully use RDAP**, only, perhaps, to try some experimental implementation... But even experimental, I not know how to try it.

## Answer to your wrong hypothesis

The URL that you used is wrong, so, in part, your question details started with  [wrong hypothesis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/205446).

The domain `RDAP.ORG` is not an "official authority", it is a owned by a commercial organization, so it is a false ".ORG". There are a footer at rdap.org pages acknowledging that is **no offcial service**, and is a `tau.uk.com` playground. Try [some RDAP client](https://github.com/DNSBelgium/rdap).

## Best interpretation and long answer

[This ICANN report](https://www.icann.org/public-comments/rdap-profile-2015-12-03-en) of 2015-12-03, "Registration Data Access Protocol (RDAP) Operational Profile for gTLD Registries and Registrars", have some clues, some history, ... and fished with

> (...) it is premature to include a requirement for all gTLDs in the RDAP Profile
> (...) A call for volunteers is planned by January 2016.

So, no one decides to enforce RDAP on all registrars...  And there are no "call for volunteers" announced this year.

#### Dream with an intermediate alternative

The main problem with WHOIS today is the "free interpretation" of the published information. [There are no "standard Rosetta stone"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37455007/287948), but [we can start one](https://github.com/ppKrauss/whois-to-semantic) (!), to offer a [maturity intermediary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model) for RDAP.

### 2019 news

Starting 2019-08-26 it will be an ICANN requirements (hence for all gTLDs) to have an RDAP server at registries and registrars.

From https://www.icann.org/rdap:

> RDAP Timeline
>
> gTLD registries and registrars are required to implement an RDAP
> service by 26 August 2019. ICANN org continues to work with gTLD
> registries and registrars to implement a service-level agreement and
> registry reporting requirements for RDAP.

Read more on RDAP timeline at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/rdap-background-2018-08-31-en

### 2020 news

**RDAP services are working!** You can try it in a *RDAP client* (as old `whois` client) or directelly in the top-level domain authority's API. Examples:

- Authority's RDAP API endpoint of the top-level domain `.com` is `https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/`. For example the Brazilian's `UOL.COM` is described at https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/uol.com .
- Authority's RDAP API endpoint of the top-level domain `.org` is `https://rdap.publicinterestregistry.net/rdap/org/`.  For example W3C's domain is described at https://rdap.publicinterestregistry.net/rdap/org/domain/w3c.org
- There are many **RDAP clients** working fine, the [OpenRDAP.org](https://www.openrdap.org/) is one. You don't need to know the authority or its RDAP API endpoint, is direct. 
  Examples:  `rdap -v uol.com` or `rdap -v w3c.org`.
- **Online clients** also can be used. Examples: [`client.rdap.org` resolving `uol.com`](https://client.rdap.org/?type=domain&object=uol.com) or [`openrdap.org` resolving `w3c.org`](https://www.openrdap.org/demo?cmd=rdap+-v+w3c.org).

**Entity transparency**: the transparency policies are local. For example `UOL.com.br` is registered by the `.br` authority, and [Registro.BR](http://Registro.br) obligates that all *domain name owner* must to be revealed (see CNPJ entry). Check it by a good and universal client, like OpenRDAP, [`rdap -v uol.com.br`](https://www.openrdap.org/demo?cmd=rdap+-v+uol.com.br).

Comment: Check also [icann.org/resources/rdap-gtld-profile-2016-07-26](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/rdap-gtld-profile-2016-07-26-en) and the first standard (!) of 2016 July, [RDAP Operational Profile for gTLD Registries and Registrars, Version 1.0](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/rdap-operational-profile-2016-07-26-en).

Comment: See also (perhaps changes in the future) http://stackoverflow.com/q/29101451/287948

Comment: The github link under "we can start one" does not work anymore.

Comment: Starting 2019-08-26 it will be an ICANN requirements (hence for all gTLDs) to have an RDAP server at registries and registrars.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek, now it is a wiki, plese edit with the good news!

Answer (score 0):

The correct url in 2020 is https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/google.com. Right now there are hundreds of domain extensions using rdap already.